# replace a partial derivative with a normal derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have an expression for the derivative of a function $\theta$: $\frac{d\theta}{dx}=f\left(x,y,\theta\right)$, where $x$ and $y$ are the usual cartesian coordinates. I am in need to find $\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}$. Is it appropiate to simply replace the partial derivative with the normal one?

EDIT: $y$ is independent of $x$.

EDIT2: I also have an expression for the other derivative: $\frac{d\theta}{dy}=g\left(x,y,\theta\right)$

Comment: If $y$ and $\theta$ both are functions of $x$.

Comment: sorry, forgot to state that $y$ is an independent variable

Comment: If $\theta$ is a function of more variables than $x$, you must write a partial derivative. If $f$ actually depends on $y$, then so must $\theta$?

Comment: the problem is, I don't have an explicit expression for $\theta$, I only have an analytic expression for its derivatives. And yes, I am assuming that $\theta$ also depends on $x$ and $y$